# How can I extract information from Arduino graph.Or from the Processing software connected with Arduino

Tags: graph, arduino, processing, arduino-uno

I am using AD8232 ECG sensor and I need PR interval, OT interval, R peak etc. I can generate the graph. But from the graph, I need these parameters to extract programmatically Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arduino software was actually based in part off of Processing - that’s the beauty of open-source projects. Once we have an open sketch, our first step is to import the Serial library. Go to Sketch->Import Library->Serial

You should now see a line like import processing.serial.*; at the top of your sketch. Magic! Underneath our import statement, we need to declare some global variables. All this means is that these variables can be used anywhere in our sketch. Add these two lines beneath the import statement:

```
Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class
String val;     // Data received from the serial port
```

In order to listen to any serial communication, we have to get a Serial object (we call it myPort but you can it whatever you like), which lets us listen in on a serial port on our computer for any incoming data. We also need a variable to receive the actual data coming in. In this case, since we’re sending a String (the sequence of characters ‘Hello, World!’) from Arduino, we want to receive a String in Processing. Just like Arduino has setup() and loop(), Processing has setup() and draw() (instead of loop).

For our setup() method in Processing, we’re going to find the serial port our Arduino is connected to and set up our Serial object to listen to that port.

```
void setup()
{
  String portName = Serial.list()[0]; //change the 0 to a 1 or 2 etc. to match your port
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
}
```

Remember how we set Serial.begin(9600) in Arduino? Well, if we don’t want that gobbledy-gook I was talking about, we had better put 9600 as that last argument in our Serial object in Processing as well. This way Arduino and Processing are communicating at the same rate. Happy times!

In our draw() loop, we’re going to listen in on our Serial port and we get something, stick that something in our val variable and prints it to the console (that black area at the bottom of your Processing sketch).

```
void draw()
{
  if ( myPort.available() > 0) 
  {  // If data is available,
  val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');         // read it and store it in val
  } 
println(val); //print it out in the console
}
```

Ta-Da! If you hit the ‘run’ button (and your Arduino is plugged in with the code on the previous page loaded up), you should see a little window pop-up, and after a sec, you should see `Hello, World!‘ appear in the Processing console. Over and over.Excellent! We’ve now conquered how to send data from Arduino to Processing. Our next step is to figure out how to go the opposite way - sending data from Processing to Arduino.

Comment: for more info look this up **https://itp.nyu.edu/physcomp/labs/labs-serial-communication/serial-output-from-an-arduino/**

Comment: Thanks for explaining all the things in a nice way. But I have done all these things. Now I have the graph, but from the graph, I want to get the mentioned valued programmatically. Can you or anyone tell me some hint about this? Thanks in advanced.